# VoIP in iOS 10 issues (Xcode 8 beta 3)

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, swift3, xcode8

When using VoIP in an app that works fine in previous iOS versions, I have some runtime issues in iOS 10. The first error I receive is:

```
Failed to install UIApplication keep alive handler. VoIP keep-alive
timer handler could not be successfully installed. ('voip' must be 
present in UIBackgroundModes in the application Plist.)
```

I have added the 'Privacy - VoIP Usage Description' key pair to Info.plist, but it is still not working. 'voip' is already in my UIBackgroundModes values too.

Once I am connecting a VoIP call (whether as the caller or recipient), I also receive the ominous error:

```
[access] <private>
```

It seems that some of these things are still changing with each additional Xcode 8 beta, but there is little to no documentation. Any idea how to fix these errors?

Comment: iOS 10 is beta software. Report bugs to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSCameraUsageDescription key was missing from my Info.plist. After adding that, to use VoIP video calling, the

```
[access] <private>
```

error was resolved.